# Referencing an index element in an array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

Here is the vardump for my array:

```
array(4) {
         [3]=> array(1) 
         {
             ["match"]=> int(33) 
         } 
         [2]=> array(1) 
         { 
             ["match"]=> int(32) 
         } 
         [1]=> array(1) 
         { 
             ["match"]=> int(16) 
         } 
         [4]=> array(1) 
         { 
             ["match"]=> int(3) 
         } 
}
```

I need to return the indexes 3, 2, 1, and 4 for use in a query. I have no idea how to do this. I need to run the query in a foreach statement:

```
foreach($arrayName as $key){
    //NEED TO RETURN INDEX HERE    
}
```

I've tried to use `key($key)` but that returned the word "match" which is the index of one level below where I need.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In fact you are using foreach with the wrong semantics. It sould be like **foreach($arrayName as $value)** if you are using two operands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy one ;)

```
$keys = array_keys($arrayName);
```

Comment: Avoid running queries in loops - you should be more than able to formulate one query to it for you by using something like IN('.implode(',',$keys).') ...

Comment: Well I thought it was going to be more complicated than that. This is my first foray into large arrays, cheers for the help

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach($arrayName as $key => $value){
    echo($key);    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($arrayName as $key)
```

The `$key` is actually the value in the array. Try:

```
foreach($arrayName as $key=>$value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the key to the foreach:

```
foreach($arrayName as $key => $value){
       echo $key; //$key is well... the key and $value is the value of the current element in the array :)
}
```